# No Messages view in AndroidStudio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building an app budle and I get an error *Generate Signed Bundle: Errors while building Bundle file. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.* but .... I've just downloaded AndroidStudio 3.3 and there's no Messages view anymore.

Or is there? Is there a way to enable it? I can't find the details of the error anywhere ...

Comment: Where is that error message appearing?

Comment: In the "Event Log" view

Comment: Try the Build view, switched from the tree to the build log output (second icon down in the vertical tool strip in that view). See if your message is there.

Comment: yeah...it is .... sigh. But it's not highlighted in any way! In red or whatever. Also, I've noticed compile time errors show up there as well, but they're not set as links. Did they disable it for some reason? I can't jump directly to the file and line now...

Comment: Also, please write your answer as an answer so I can accept it....

Comment: "Did they disable it for some reason?" -- it might vary by where the message comes from. File a feature request!

Comment: My colleague has them enabled. So if he has a missing ";" in his code, the IDE will show an error in the build view and the error will be a link (as it was previously in Messages) and he just clicks on it and jumps to where the issue is. On my IDE it's something like: http://puu.sh/CAED9/9320b2a0e3.png ... Can't click it. Can one enable that or ... do I have some sort of bug ... i wonder.

Comment: I've made a question for this a couple of days ago but no solution ... yet ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233205/androidstudio-build-tab-has-no-link-to-file-and-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages was removed in AS 3.2 (I think, definitely by AS 3.3). It was replaced by a secondary mode for the Build tool. By default, that tool shows a tree output of the build. The second toolbar button in the toolstrip will toggle it between that view and the raw output of the Gradle build.

Comment: Android Studio 3.5.1 is STILL telling people to they may find a scrap of information about why their build failed in the still non-existent "Messages" view. Sigh. Thanks.   . . . I notice too that it says that when trying to make a signed APK, but there are no errors there. Guess I just need to guess what went wrong trying to sign my APK.

Comment: Update: Android Studio **3.6.1** is STILL telling people to they may find a scrap of information about why their build failed in the still non-existent "Messages" view.

Comment: So is 4.1.2 ... and it's more than a year old.